# Run Time Permission check license Android M

Tags: android, permissions, runtime, licensing, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a problem with the runtime permission.
I'm updating my Android application to support Android M and the new system of permission.

I took a look at the code example and I think I have understood the operation, instead of what I can not implement is a specific permission.
I'm talking about `com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE`, to use it I resort to a package provided by the same google.

Looking at `Manifest.Permission` no permission like this, does anyone know how to implement it?

Comment: `com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE` is not one of the listed runtime permissions. Is using this permission normally not working on Android 6.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample given by google for runtime permission should be applied to all permission considered dangereous and listed here in table1: 
[here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)

com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE is not part of these dangerous permission.
It is enough to declare it in the manifest.

Eventually I did not have time to test if there is some other problem linked to the new SDK with this permission.

Comment: I cannot find the table in the link you provided, the table now is at: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: thank you, with the official release of Android 6.0, the table moved. I edited the post.